# Access temporary image from temp directory in tomcat (liferay)

Tags: tomcat, liferay

I get from an interface an image (base64 decoded), this will be encoded and i try to create a temporary image into the temp folder of tomcat. Is there a possibility to access these files via url in the temp folder? Or is this just a bad idea? 
The reason, why i am creating temporary files is, that i dont want to manage the deletion of the files and so on.

```
File iconFile = File.createTempFile("ppoiIcons", currentIcon.getIconFileName()+".jpg");
FileUtil.write(iconFile, decodeBytes(currentIcon.getIconAttachment()));
System.out.println("iconFilePath: " + iconFile.getAbsolutePath());
currentIcon.setIconFileName(iconFile.getAbsolutePath());
```

After the creation of the temporary files, i want to reference via html img-tag into a jsp page.
Something like this:

```
<img src="localhost:8080/temp/tempIcon.jpg">
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Instead create file under some ROOT/images folder or in your portlet (abcportlet/images)and reference it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

of course: Create a DownloadServlet, ImageServlet or something similar and bind it to the url /temp/*

Your good choice is to put that image into a temp folder, not into a directory in your actual web application. The bad news is that there's no appserver-automatic way to serve the temp folder you chose to the internet. Well - bad news? Not actually: Due to this constraint you're safe from a number of attack vectors, e.g. somebody might upload an image with the name "attack.jsp" - this might end up being interpreted/executed serverside, something you won't want. Also, on redeployment of your app, you'll loose all of the files uploaded to your webapp.

Such a Download Servlet is typically easy and you'll most likely find several sample installations by just googling it. Depending on the size of the images, you might want to implement things like caching, partial downloads or other features, but a pure download should be really easy.